# Motorbee code C++

Tags: c++

I'm trying to control a motor via a device called a [Motor-Bee](https://www.pc-control.co.uk/motorbee_info.htm), and using C++.

This is the code I'm using :

```
#include <iostream.h>
#include <mt.h>
#include <windows.h>
#pragma hdrstop


int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{

HINSTANCE HStpDll; // declaration of variable to hold the handle to the dll
HStpDll = LoadLibrary( _T("mtb.dll")); // load the dll into memory and return handle


Type_InitMotoBee InitMotoBee;
Type_SetMotors SetMotors;

InitMotoBee = (Type_InitMotoBee)GetProcAddress( HStpDll, " InitMotoBee");

SetMotors =(Type_SetMotors)GetProcAddress(HStpDll, " SetMotors");


InitMotoBee();
    SetMotors(0, 50, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0);

return 0;
}
```

mt.h and mtb.dll are files which come with the device.

When I try to run the program, all I get is a box pop up saying:

> "Project2.exe raised exception classEAccessViolation with message 'Access violation at address 00000000.
>   Read of address 00000000'. Process stopped. Use step or Run to continue."

A PDF manual with info about C++ functions can [be found here](https://www.pc-control.co.uk/images/Motor-Bee%20Manual.pdf).

Could anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong? Or, course how to solve it if possible.

Comment: Perhaps GetProcAddress returning nullptr? Try you delete spaces before function names?

Comment: which line throws the access violation? did you debug it? What's the return value of LoadLibrary?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have spaces before the function names in the `GetProcAddress()` calls, that seems very wrong.

Also, you're not checking the returned pointers for validness before using them, which is why it crashes when the lookup fails.

Comment: Thank you!That first suggestion solved it. I was hoping it'd be something simple like that.